# Locate largest absolute value in off-diagonal elements of a symmetric matrix

Tags: r, linear-algebra

I would like to find the location and value of the largest absolute value in the off-diagonal elements in a symmetric matrix in R.

For example, with this small 3x3 :

```
 matrix(c(99,11,-21, 11,99,13, -21,13,99), nrow = 3, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

       [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]   99   11  -21
 [2,]   11   99   13
 [3,]  -21   13   99
```

I want to know -21 as the value and either 1,3 or 3,1 as the location

Are there any neat ways to do this other than by "brute force" ?

Thanks
PS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes to programming, it's always hard to know what someone else considers to be 'brute force'. That said, for a square matrix (here named `M`), you could do something like this:

```
m <- M
diag(m) <- NA

(mmax <- max(abs(m), na.rm=TRUE))
# [1] -21

which(abs(m) == mmax, arr.ind=TRUE)
#      row col
# [1,]   3   1
# [2,]   1   3
```

Comment: Perfect. I certainly don't consider that brute force ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- matrix(c(99,11,-21, 11,99,13, -21,13,99), nrow = 3, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
diag(x) <- NA
which(abs(x) == max(abs(x),na.rm=T), arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#create matrix
m <- matrix(c(99,11,-21, 11,99,13, -21,13,99), nrow = 3, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE) 
#remove diagonal
diag(m) <- 0

#find locations of max absolute value using norm
which(abs(m) == norm(m,type="m"),arr.ind=TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   3   1
[2,]   1   3
```